# Why isn't $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{2})$ a splitting field for $x^{2}+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I'm working through Dummit and Foote's algebra textbook. An exercise asks to determine the splitting field and degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $x^{2}+2$.

I have what I think is an accurate solution, but I must have made a mistake somewhere because it does not line up with the true answer. Here's my solution:

First, it's easy to see that $x^{2}+2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (it's a quadratic with no root in $\mathbb{Q}$). So the splitting field of $x^{2} + 2$ is not $\mathbb{Q}$ itself, and so the splitting field has degree $\geq 2$.

Noting that $x^{2} + 2 = (x - i \sqrt{2})(x + i \sqrt{2})$, I determined that the splitting field must contain $\pm i \sqrt{2}$. So I thought to check $\mathbb{Q}[i \sqrt{2}]$, which definitely contains these two roots. Then $x^{2}+2$ definitely splits over $\mathbb{Q}[i \sqrt{2}]$.

Since $i \sqrt{2}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ (as we've seen, it's a root of $x^{2}+2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$), we know $\mathbb{Q}[i \sqrt{2}]$ is a field (and so an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$).

So then $\mathbb{Q}[i \sqrt{2}] = \{a + b i \sqrt{2} : a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, and it has the basis $\{1, i \sqrt{2}\}$ when viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. So it's a vector space of dimension 2, and so the extension has degree $[\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$.

But this doesn't line up with the true solution, which says that the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{2})$, which can be seen to be of degree $4$. Can anyone see an error in this solution?

Comment: The splitting field of $x^2+2$ over $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb Q(i\sqrt2)$, not $\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt2)$. Period.

Comment: Like you said, $X^2 + 2$ splits over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$, and it's clearly a minimal such extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying my solution is correct? If that's the case, my list of "solutions" to check myself against must be incorrect...

Comment: A splitting field of a polynomial of degree $n$ has degree at most $n!$ over the ground field. In particular, the splitting field of a quadratic has either degree 1 or 2, never 4.

Comment: Don’t trust the internet!